# R: Is there a way to generate a heatmap of the dissimilarity matrix only and sort it by cluster?

Tags: r, heatmap, categorical-data

I am using hclust to find clusters among 266 observations. All the variables are categorical. I am trying to create a heatmap of the dissimilarity matrix created from the `daisy` function, to visualise the within cluster similarity. I am using the `heatmap` function:

```
heatmap(x, Rowv = NULL, Colv = if(symm)"Rowv" else NULL,
        distfun = dist, hclustfun = hclust,
        reorderfun = function(d, w) reorder(d, w),
        add.expr, symm = FALSE, revC = identical(Colv, "Rowv"),
        scale = c("row", "column", "none"), na.rm = TRUE,
        margins = c(5, 5), 
        cexRow = 0.2 + 1/log10(nr), cexCol = 0.2 + 1/log10(nc),
        labRow = NULL, labCol = NULL, main = NULL,
        xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
        keep.dendro = FALSE, verbose = getOption("verbose"))
```

However, this function requires x to be a numeric matrix.I tried to enter my dissimilarity matrix instead using `data.matrix(data, metric="gower")` but when I do it considers the matrix as the dataset. The function `heatmap.2` (which may have some additional settings) is not available in the R version I am using.

The second part of my question is if there is a way to reorder the heatmap in way that each cluster is clearly underlined on it. I was trying :

```
x <- cutree(hclust.object, 4)
#cluster number=4
cluster.membership <- factor(assignCluster(data, data, x))
```

And then set the following in the `heatmap` function:

```
reorderfun = function(hclust.object, cluster.membership) reorder(hclust.object, cluster.membership)
```

The results seem to be ordered as expected. However, I still can not find a way to visualise the clustering results on the heatmap (e.g. by using legends).

Answer (score 1):

By using `pheatmap` function in `pheatmap` package, you can generate heatmap with clusters based on your dissimilarity matrix.

Assuming `data` is your dataset and `hclust.object` is hclust object produced based on dissimilarity matrix;

```
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(data, cluster_rows = hclust.object, cutree_rows = 4)
```

should give you heatmap, which is clustered based on hclust object, which is generated by your dissimilarity matrix.
You can also use other parameters in `pheatmap` function as you like.

For further information, use `?pheatmap`.